# Authorization information in swagger codegen

Tags: swagger-codegen

I'm starting out with Swagger for my **REST APIs**. The primary goal is to generate server files for Nancy endpoints from Swagger definition. I downloaded the sources and modified the generated files for Nancy to my needs using `api.moustache` file.

Everything works fine but for one thing: some of the endpoints are protected, while some are not. In docu for swagger format I found that one can provide authentication information per endpoint. Now I want to access this info and if authentication is needed generate in my Nancy module `RequireAuthentication()`-line.

I located the moustache file and the java file for Nancy generator, but I cannot figure out where and how can I access the authentication info from swagger definition?

Comment: Per endpoint the information is on `authMethods`, this API client template in perl works as an example https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/c66a0aaa07695276fc3fa6a24bb42d2176d0f5cc/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/perl/ApiClient.mustache#L331 plus here you can find a way to see all the tags that can be used on the template for both the operations and models in the language you are generating https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Mustache-Template-Variables it's really useful when you don't know where the information is

Answer (score 0):

After more searching and exploring, I found out the way to edit moustache.api:

```
{{#operations}}{{#operation}}

{{#hasAuthMethods}}this.RequireAuthentication();{{/hasAuthMethods}}

{{/operation}}{{/operations}}
```